# Looping an Array with Missing Keys in Ansible Tasks

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to create an Ansible Role to create users... I want it to be able to accept a list of dicts and if a key is missing from the dict, it will fall back to Ansible's default.

For example, given the following data:

```yml
---
users:
 - { name: foo, group: bar, create_home: no }
   { name: goo, group: bar }
```

I'd normally loop over the list with something like:

```yml
- name: Add users
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    groups: "{{ item.group }}"
    create_home: "{{ item.create_home }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ users }}"
```

However, because `create_home` doesn't exist for the second user, it'd throw an error. How could I get it to fall back to Ansible's default for keys that don't exist?

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**How could I get it to fall back to Ansible's default for keys that don't exist?**"*

A: [Omit](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) such parameters, e.g.

```yaml
    create_home: "{{ item.create_home|default(omit) }}"
```

Comment: Oh, that looks to be exactly what I needed... thanks!  I'm really not a fan of Ansible's documentation; I don't find it to be very newcomer friendly.  I'll give it a try later when I have some time and I'll accept this as the solution if it works, which I'm sure it will. 